# ¿Cómo asociar una extensión de archivo al editor del SQL del management studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Tengo una serie de archivos con código `SQL` pero con distintas extensiones, digamos por caso `*.txt`, al leerlos desde el **SQL Management Studio**, no los considera código `SQL` por lo que tengo dos problemas:

1. La sintaxis no se resalta
2. Más grave, no puedo ejecutar este código

¿De que forma hacer que la extensión `*.txt` sea considerada código `SQL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al menos con un **SSMS** en inglés, hay que ir al menú "Tools" ítem "Options" y buscar la configuración "Text editor" y dentro de esta "File Extension" (Ruta: `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregar la nueva extensión deseada, asociarla al **SQL Query Editor** y tener en cuenta que se reconocerá la misma como código `SQL` a partir de  este momento (pestañas ya abiertas no se actualizan)